# Which association is sorted in that line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sorting, associations

If the `Input` model `has_many :translations`, which translations row is sorted?

```
Input.includes(:translations).order("translations.value DESC")
```

**models**

```
class Input < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :input
  belongs_to :language
end

# translations table schema:
# id          :integer
# value       :string
# input_id    :integer
# language_id :integer
```

I need to list all the Inputs, with 8 columns (for the 8 languages I have associated with the Translation) sorted by the value of the translation on the first language (set arbitrarily).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, all of the rows of your Input table are used to join the Translations table, so all of the joined rows will be sorted by `value` from the Translations table.

Since you don't provide any `where` condition on your query for the Input table, all rows from the input table are used, which it sounds like is your intent.

You're using `includes` in your query, when you almost certainly mean `joins`.  While these are syntactically interchangeable in many cases, they're semantically intended for different purposes.

`includes` is specifically provided to facilitate [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), whereas `joins` is defined to support [joining tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).  The rule of thumb is that if you want to use any of the columns from the joined table in the query, use `joins`, otherwise, you can use `includes` to eager load the association.

The result that you're looking to get is fairly difficult to do with just SQL.  However, you can easily get the Input rows and the association and use a simple Ruby collection transform to get the results that you want, including placeholders for missing values from Translations.

Try this:

```
languages = Language.all.order("name")
inputs = Input.includes(:translations).order("id")
translations = inputs.map do |input|
  { 
    input.id => languages.map do |language| 
                  item = input.translations.find_index {|i| i.language_id == language.id }
                  item ? nil : input.translations[item]
                end
  }
end
```

This will return an array of hashes, it the `input.id` as the key and the 8-column table of translations supplied for each.  `nil` is used as the placeholder for translations that don't exist for an input, so you can use that as an indication in your view to insert the "Translate..." option.  This is how it could be used:

```
<table>
<% inputs.each do |input| %>
    <tr>
    <% translation = translations[input.id] %>
    <% translation.each do |item| %>
      <% item %>
          <td class="translation-available"><%= item.value %></td>
      <% else %>
          <td><%= link_to "Translate...", translate_input_path(input) %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, I mocked in some structure and design elements in order to show you how to process the `inputs` array; you can adapt it to suit your view structure, as necessary.

Comment: thanks, the Inputs table works fine. Now, how can I sort the inputs alphabetically by the language?

Comment: The first line of the code is `languages = Language.all.order("name")`.  If you change the field that you use to order, it will change the order of the languages displayed here.  I assume that your Language model has a `name` field, but you can put whichever field fits best here for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The `value` column of your `translations` table. It will generate an SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT "inputs"."id" AS t0_r0, "inputs"."name" AS t0_r1, ..., 
    "translations"."id" AS t1_r0, "translations"."value" AS t1_r1, ...
FROM "inputs"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations"
    ON "translations"."input_id" = "inputs"."id"  
ORDER BY translations.value DESC   // <== YOUR `.order()` method
```

As you can see, the ordering is done in DB, not Rails. So, the ordering will be whatever your DB ordering is.

Comment: But one input can have more than one translation, so wich one the sorting algorithym is using?

Comment: @ViniciusFontoura the sort uses *all* of them. Each "input" will occur potentially more than once in the query you show.

Comment: I see. Ive updated the questions with more info and context. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added an image.